# Generating c# classes from Json Object

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON Object which I am struggling to convert into classes (in order to deserialize the contents). I believe it should be a list of classes, but unsure which class would be the List.

I have tried online tools to help convert into the c# class(s) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
"{"cod":"200","message":0.0024,"cnt":5,"list":[{"dt":1502334000,"main":{"temp":19.45,"temp_min":16.26,"temp_max":19.45,"pressure":1001.58,"sea_level":1035.49,"grnd_level":1001.58,"humidity":81,"temp_kf":3.19},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0,"deg":0},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2016-08-10 03:00:00"},{"dt":1502388000,"main":{"temp":28.29,"temp_min":25.9,"temp_max":28.29,"pressure":999.8,"sea_level":1033.29,"grnd_level":999.8,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":2.39},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0,"deg":0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-08-10 18:00:00"},{"dt":1502398800,"main":{"temp":27,"temp_min":25.41,"temp_max":27,"pressure":998.64,"sea_level":1032.04,"grnd_level":998.64,"humidity":79,"temp_kf":1.59},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":64},"wind":{"speed":0,"deg":0},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-08-10 21:00:00"},{"dt":1502452800,"main":{"temp":19.28,"temp_min":18.48,"temp_max":19.28,"pressure":997.72,"sea_level":1031.52,"grnd_level":997.72,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":0.8},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":{"all":48},"wind":{"speed":2.66,"deg":182.504},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-08-11 12:00:00"},{"dt":1502474400,"main":{"temp":25.91,"temp_min":25.91,"temp_max":25.91,"pressure":996.5,"sea_level":1029.96,"grnd_level":996.5,"humidity":0,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.77,"deg":232.001},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2016-08-11 18:00:00"}],"city":{"id":4517009,"name":"London","coord":{"lat":39.8865,"lon":-83.4483},"country":"US"}}"
```

Comment: Use Json.NET, and parse the json into a `JObject` using `JObject.Parse`. You will be able to access your fields using indexer notation, like `myJobj["cod"]`, or `myJobj["list"]["dt"]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example JSON cannot be expressed as one class. Its several classes.

You can try this great resource: http://jsonutils.com/Home/Index?url=about%3Ablank.

OUTPUT (using default options):

```
public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public string pod { get; set; }
    }

    public class List
    {
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public IList<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coord
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }
        public IList<List> list { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
    }
```

You can modify how property names are generated and what if any namespace your classes should reside in.

Please note: you'll have to remove the very first and very last quotes from your JSON that wrap it.

Comment: Many thanks Dmitri. I am pretty new to using Json objects / API's so will bear this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio 2013 onward to generate class from JSON.

Visual studio menu -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes

Comment: You should also mention what version of VS

Answer (score 0):

The following website will take JSON as an input and will generate C# classes. Will be useful when you want to de-serialize JSON to C# POCO object.

http://json2csharp.com/

http://jsonutils.com/